# How to implement MVVM with the WPF treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I haven't worked with WPF or the MVVM pattern before.
However I want to create a simple document management system and would like to do so using the aforementioned technologies.

I've modeled a hierarchical file system in my Database and want to display it in a treeview.
[EER-Diagramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Btd1.png)
As you can see each directory can have multiple sub-directories and multiple files in it.

I've read some tutorials on the topic and if I understood them correctly then I should create model classes for directory and file in which the data from the database is stored directly.
Example:

```
public class Directory
{
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private int parent;
    public int Parent
    {
        get { return parent; }
        set { parent = value; }
    }

    private DateTime dateCreatedOn;
    public DateTime DateCreatedOn
    {
        get { return dateCreatedOn; }
        set { dateCreatedOn = value; }
    }
}
```

Then each model class should have an associated view-model class which implements additional properties which are only relevant for describing the UI element to which objects of this class will be bound.
In this case the view-model class should have the isExpanded and isSelected Property of the treeviewitem.
Then I would need another view-model class for the entire treeview which would contain the collection of directorys and files which should be displayed.

My questions are:

1. Have I understood the mvvm concept correctly?
2. Which class, the model or the view-model, of directory should implement the iNotifyPropertyChanged interface?
3. Should the view-model class of directory contain the same properties as the model class or is a reference to a model-object in the view-model class sufficient?
4. If the view-model class should contain the same properties of the model class again, then whats the best way to make sure that model-objects and the associated view-model objects always stay synchronized?

I hope this question is understandable and thanks for all help.
Andahari

Comment: Questions 2-4 have surely been asked before individually.

Comment: HierarchicalDataTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer 1) yes.

answer 2) view-model should have the iNotifyPropertyChanged.

answer 3) yes. and they should be explicitly mapped. i.e.:

```
   this.property1 = model.property1
```

answer 4) use the same names, and see answer 3.

If you use a private-public property pair in the view-model, use iNotifyPropertyChanged in the view-Model, and map the properties of the model to the corresponding properties in the view-model, you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Model also can implement the iNotifyPropertyChanged, you no need to repeat the properties in View Model again.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(PandP.40).aspx

"The model may also support data validation and error reporting through the IDataErrorInfo (or INotifyDataErrorInfo) interfaces. The IDataErrorInfo and INotifyDataErrorInfo interfaces allow WPF data binding to be notified when values change so that the UI can be updated. They also enable support for data validation and error reporting in the UI layer."